# Expansion of complex equation.

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

Find the value of $$\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^{15}  + \left(\frac{-1-\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^{15}.$$

In general, how do we find the value of expansion of equation of high orders other than binomial expansion?

Comment: If you notice that $\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^3=1$, the rest should be easy. (For these particular numbers.)

Comment: There is no equation in the question, so the title is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the length of $a:=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ equals $1$ and its argument is $2\pi/3$.  Hence $a^{15}=1$. Analog $\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^{15}=1$.  Hence their sum equals $2$.

Comment: Don't you mean $a^{15}=1$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the correctionS.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Corrected

Comment: +1. I don't understand why people are making this seem harder than it is.

Answer (score 12):

In general, if you want to find powers of a complex number, write it in polar form i.e. in the form of $r e^{i \theta} $ so that $(r e^{i \theta})^n = r^n e^{i n \theta} $. Then you can convert it back to $a + ib$ form easily as $r^n \cos(n \theta) + i r^n \sin(n \theta) $.

Answer (score 3):

If you notice that $\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^3=1$, the rest should be easy.

---

Let me suggest another possible solution, although perhaps not the quickest way.

Using the fact that the given numbers are the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2+x+1=0$, you should be able to show that
$$a_n=\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^{n}  + \left(\frac{-1-\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^{n}$$
fulfills the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) $a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_n=0$. (For example, you can prove this by induction.)

Now you can find $a_{15}$ using $a_0=2$, $a_1=-1$ and $a_{n+2}=-a_{n+1}-a_{n+1}$.

If you try this, you should notice a repeating patter after a few terms.

Comment: +1 for the first part. I'm not sure what I think about the multitude of harder ways that are being posted.

Comment: notice that your general formula for $a_n$ don't have a $n$ in it.

Comment: @Héctor Thanks for noticing, corrected.

Comment: @robjohn If tte OP has been exposed to recurrence relation before, the other possibility is quite natural. And it might work for different numbers, too. I considered it interesting enough to be at least mentioned.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I have no problem with alternate methods and your alternate method is good; it answers the more general part of the question. My comment was more in reaction to some of the more obscure approaches to a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$
Also you can use DeMovire's Theorem.

Comment: This is just a hint. If we will always try to just solve their problems, they'll never learn to apply things on their own.

Answer (score 0):

And more generally, to find an irreducible representation of the field we work on will ensure that matrix exponentiation reduces to exponentiation of the individual blocks of the representation matrix. Such a matrix for $re^{i\theta}$ is $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} r&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&\theta&1 \end{array}\right)$$ since:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} r_1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&\theta_1&1 \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{ccc} r_2&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&\theta_2&1 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} r_1r_2&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&\theta_1+\theta_2&1 \end{array}\right)$$

Then it is trivial to show that: $$\prod_{i=1}^N \left(\begin{array}{ccc} r_i&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&\theta_i&1 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} \prod_{i=1}^N r_i&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&\sum_{I=1}^N\theta_i&1 \end{array}\right)$$ just as with polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Exploiting Martin Sleziak's comment, we notice the two addends are fifth powers of one, since the bases of both those powers are cubic roots of one. Therefore that sum is $1+1=2$.

Comment: Must have missed the plus... fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^{15}  + \left(\frac{-1-\sqrt 3i}{2}\right)^{15}=$$

$$\left(\frac{2e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}}{2e^{oi}}\right)^{15}  + \left(\frac{2e^{-\frac{2}{3}\pi i}}{2e^{oi}}\right)^{15}=$$

$$(e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i})^{15}+(e^{-\frac{2}{3}\pi i})^{15}=$$

$$e^{10\pi i}+e^{-10\pi i}=2$$